# Unable to add python sdk to Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an empty `Intellij` project that has just the default `java` SDK included:

[image]

Now I have already added a `python` script to the project: but the imports are unresolved since no python sdk is defined. So let's try to add it.  First click o the *+* and we are asked for the python sdk root directory. Here it is on my mac:

[image]

I click on 'Open':

[image]

But then ***nothing*** happens. No error messages .. but also no new `python` SDK. 
So what's the special sauce to get python onboard here?

Comment: select python launcher and test again and tell what happen

Comment: @sahama *Where*/*how* to select the python launcher? If I have to delete the  project and start over that would be less than desirable. It may be *necessary* .. but then why does IJ even *have* the "add SDK" option if it does not work?

Comment: perhaps problem is that you have to chose a python executable.

Comment: @sahama  Looks like that may be correct.  The directions I saw had said *directory* of the SDK - so those were incorrect. So - how about making it an answer and I can award.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the SDK location choose the actual python executable instead of the dirctory.