# Workaround to select python SDK in Intellij 2018.2

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I am having a problem that seems to a possible bug of Intellij 2018.X

I am running Intellij 2018.2 (but the same happens with 2018.1) and I am unable to add Python SDK. My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

The problem is located in **Project Structure** screen. There when I click on **Add New SDK** > **Python SDK**, it does nothing but totally ignores me, neither the popup to choose the location is shown nor an error or warning.

Same happens in SDK selectors of **Project Structure** > **Project** > **Project Settings** and in **Project Structure** > **SDKs**.

[image: No popup appear to select the location of Python SDK]

It's not the same as [Unable to add Python SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41919891/unable-to-add-python-sdk-to-intellij-idea) because in that, the user has the popup to select the path.

Do you know any workaround for this?

Comment: I really suggest to address this in the [IntelliJ community](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200382555-IntelliJ-IDEA-Users) or with the [respective support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us#). Especially when you think that this is a bug. Although some SO users might be able to help with issues concerning certain tools, the respective vendors and their communities are probably much more capable to do so.

Comment: I have edited the question. I will report the bug for sure but what I am willing to have now is a workaround not to have to wait for a patch or new version of the program. Thanks for your comment in any case ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets solved with a patch of Intellij, now my version is:

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.3 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-182.4323.46

Answer (score 0):

Please enable SSH Remote Run and Remote Hosts Access plugins, restart IntelliJ and check the problem again.

Could you please try this again and then upload your log folder zipped to https://uploads.services.jetbrains.com/? After uploading please provide the name of the zip file so we can find it. How to locate log - https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085